# Executable of a working Python code generates error "Couldn't open [DIRECTORY] no such file or directory exists"

Tags: python, directory, executable

P.S. I'm a very newbie programmer, I don't even use Python in any of my work, that said, I'm required to create this code regardless of whether I want to or not, I apparently offended some in my last post because of how absolutely categorically awful it was, if this happens to you with this post, here's your apology, sorry. Moving on...

The portion of the code where the problem arises from:

```
#window_layout
path =  directory + '/unknown.png'
layout = [[sg.Button("Browse")], [sg.Text("Face Detector")],[sg.Image(filename=path)]]
```

As said, the code runs fine in Python, but when I create an executable, it gives me an error stating "Your window has an image element with a problem" and states at another part of the window "Couldn't open "C:\users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp_ME1227922/unknown.png": no such file or directory exists."

While creating the executable, this is what I write:

```
pyinstaller Recognition.py --onefile -w
```

Error appearing upon starting the .exe file:
[image: Error appearing upon starting the .exe file]

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is even if I use
```
path =  directory + '\\unknown.png'
```
It still gives the same error.
In addition, trying to add the image during the executable creation gives the exact error as well.

Comment: Where did `directory` come from?

Comment: And you've checked manually to make sure the image file exists at that path on the device where this `exe` is being executed?

Comment: Your question has `Temp_ME1227922/unknown.png` and your screenshot has `Temp\_ME1227922/unknown.png`, can you confirm what the value of `directory` actually is?

Comment: The reason the question and screenshot are different comes from an error on my part, I apologize for that.
The directory is the Python projects path, I keep the image in that directory and get it fetched from there while running the code and it runs fine, but when I do that with the executable file, it displays the same error. Sorry if that wasn't clear.
The image is in the location of my python projects folder, I've tried to put the .exe file in the same directory as the image, but it gives the same error regardless.
Directory